# Is it possible to show a custom page for AWS Amplify 403 error?

Tags: aws-amplify

I have deployed a static website to AWS Amplify, when trying to access a page that does not exist I get a XML 403 Forbidden, is there a way to show a custom page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redirects on amplify but if you get 403 there probably may be misconfiguration in your app, if this link doesn't help please share your configs and rewrite & redirect settings on amplify.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#types-of-redirects